# Inject my own service to Activiti Api service task

Tags: activiti, inject

I am working on exposing the Activiti Api through my own service.
In one of the serviceTasks, I need to use my own service(say, XyzService),

I tried using setter/getter, it doesn't work,anyway I dont have to use getter/setter,
Is there any other way to inject this XyzService in this serviceTask, so that I can use it?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you use Spring in your project?

Comment: I am not using Spring for Activiti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following approach:

Add beans map that contains `xyzService` to the `ProcessEngineConfiguration` before building `ProcessEngine`. Objects from the map will be accesible in expressions by the key. For example:

```
ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl cfg =
    (ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl) ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration();

Map<Object, Object> beans = new HashMap<>();
beans.put("xyzService", new XyzService());

ProcessEngine engine = cfg.setBeans(beans).buildProcessEngine();
```

Inject service into service task using [Field Injection](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#serviceTaskFieldInjection)

```
<serviceTask id="servicetask" name="Service Task" activiti:class="com.example.MyJavaDelegate">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:field name="xyzServiceExp">
      <activiti:expression>${xyzService}</activiti:expression>
    </activiti:field>
  </extensionElements>
</serviceTask>
```

Where `MyJavaDelegate` is

```
public class MyJavaDelegate implements JavaDelegate {

    private Expression xyzServiceExp;

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        XyzService xyzService = (XyzService) xyzServiceExp.getValue(execution);
        ....
    }

    public void setXyzServiceExp(Expression xyzServiceExp) {
        this.xyzServiceExp = xyzServiceExp;
    }
}
```

Or you can put `JavaDelegate` instance with injected service into the `beans` map and define service task as

```
<serviceTask id="servicetask" name="Service Task"
        activiti:delegateExpression="${myJavaDelegateInstance}" />
```